# Copying the data from one table to other table in oracle database using Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am new to Java and

I have a table name TABLE1 having column names NAME, ROLL.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(NAME VARCHAR2(4), ROLL NUMBER(3));

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('SAMY', 101);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('TAMY', 102);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('JAMY', 103);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('RAMY', 104);
```

I have an other table name TABLE2 having column names NAME, ROLL.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(NAME VARCHAR2(4), ROLL NUMBER(3));
```

We need to write a Java program to migrate the data from TABLE 1 to TABLE2 in oracle and print the result in console.

I am using Oracle SQL developer.
I have written a Java program but not sure whether it is accurate or not.

```
    java.lang.Class;
    java.sql.Connection;
    java.sql.DriverManager;
    java.sql.ResultSet;
    java.sql.Statement;

    public class JDBCDemoConnection
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          try
             {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                Connection connection = null;
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "username", "password");
                Statement smt = connection.createStatement();
                String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE2 (NAME,ROLL)" + "SELECT NAME, ROLL FROM TABLE1";
                
                int i = smt.executeUpdate(sql);
                System.out.println(i+ " row is inserted into the table");

                connection.close();

             }
            catch(Exception E)
             {
               System.out.println(E);
             }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to write a program for that? You can execute the insert statement directly in the database

Comment: I am new to IntelliJ and I want to write a Java program and I need to get/print the result in Console in IntelliJ

Comment: What is your question? If you want to know if it is accurate, you should run it first.

Comment: It is showing errors and not able to find the errors..Is there something code, I need to update or include...I researched about it for long hours and not able to figure out the error correction as I am writing this program for the first time

Comment: what errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the SQL query you are using. After concatenation, the query looks like `INSERT INTO TABLE2 (NAME,ROLL) SELECT NAME, ROLL FROM TABLE1` which is not a valid SQL statement.

Simply make use of `SELECT INTO` statement to copy data from one table into a new table.

```
Statement smt = connection.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT NAME, ROLL INTO TABLE2 FROM TABLE1";
boolean result = smt.execute(sql);
```